# d3.js change path target or increase lines

Tags: d3.js

using [the bl.ocks collapsable tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example: how do I increase the length of the lines between the circles (or move the circles further out, to the right)? I know I can style the lines easily using CSS and I can update the circle sizes easily in the script... but my text is longer and it is overlaid when the children are exposed. Better still would be either: 
* calculate the max length of text in that set of children and set the new children out past the current set of children. 
or
* when exposing children, move the current set of children apart so the child that is now also a parent, has room at top/bottom to accommodate it's children.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tree.nodeSize()` function to set the height and width of the spacing. The thing to note is that if you are following the code posted above, it is using the `tree.size()` function and the both of these can't be used at the same time. Here is the documentation for the `tree.nodeSize()` function: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#nodeSize.